# Check in a website if an App is installed on tablet

Tags: c#

Is it possible to check for the existence of an app on a mobile device from a website?

Currently I am developing a website in C# that has to have the ability to choose whether to open the concerned app or to install it.

Comment: In Android you can set urls to be opened by apps. For example if you visit a StackExchange site with the app installed, the OS will pop up saying whether you want to open it with the app or the browser. Simply then all you do is on your website either pop up a message saying that you have an app with a link or immediately redirect them to the appropriate page on Play Store. No idea about iPhones though.

Comment: There is something in iOS. I get nags about installing apps on my iPad when I visit certain sites - I guess they would go away if I installed it. It's all very device specific though, and probably has limited developer control. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html

Answer (score 1):

(I am assuming ASP.NET here as you didn't specify.)

Yes you can if the tablet sends the correct user agent string.

I have attached my current platform.browser file but this may have inaccuracies.  The content is placed in the `App_Browsers` ASP.NET folder.  The reason for the patch file is Microsoft's isn't always up-to date and have some missing information.

Android is a problem but v3 is tablet only 4 may not be and I haven't had time to correct this further.

To access this information use `Request.Browser.Platform` and `Request.Browser.Version`

```
<browsers>
    <gateway id="PlatformWindowsPhone" parentID="Platform">
        <identification>
            <userAgent match="Windows Phone" />
        </identification>
        <capabilities>
            <capability name="platform" value="Windows Phone" />
        </capabilities>
    </gateway>

    <gateway id="PlatformIE11" parentID="PlatformWinnt">
        <identification>
            <userAgent match="Trident/7.0" />
            <userAgent match="rv:11.0" />
        </identification>
        <capabilities>
            <capability name="browser" value="IE" />
            <capability name="version" value="11.0" />
        </capabilities>
    </gateway>

    <gateway id="PlatformiPad" parentID="Platform">
        <identification>
            <userAgent match="iPad" />
        </identification>
        <capabilities>
            <capability name="platform" value="iPad" />
        </capabilities>
    </gateway>

    <gateway id="PlatformiPhone" parentID="Platform">
        <identification>
            <userAgent match="iPhone" />
        </identification>
        <capabilities>
            <capability name="platform" value="iPhone" />
        </capabilities>
    </gateway>

    <gateway id="PlatformAndroid" parentID="Platform">
        <identification>
            <userAgent match="Android" />
        </identification>
        <capabilities>
            <capability name="platform" value="Android" />
        </capabilities>
    </gateway>

    <gateway id="PlatformAndroid50" parentID="Platform">
        <identification>
            <userAgent match="Android 5\.0" />
        </identification>
        <capabilities>
            <capability name="version" value="5.0" />
        </capabilities>
    </gateway>

    <gateway id="PlatformAndroid45" parentID="Platform">
        <identification>
            <userAgent match="Android 4\.5" />
        </identification>
        <capabilities>
            <capability name="version" value="4.5" />
        </capabilities>
    </gateway>

    <gateway id="PlatformAndroid44" parentID="Platform">
        <identification>
            <userAgent match="Android 4\.4" />
        </identification>
        <capabilities>
            <capability name="version" value="4.4" />
        </capabilities>
    </gateway>

    <gateway id="PlatformAndroid43" parentID="Platform">
        <identification>
            <userAgent match="Android 4\.3" />
        </identification>
        <capabilities>
            <capability name="version" value="4.3" />
        </capabilities>
    </gateway>

    <gateway id="PlatformAndroid42" parentID="Platform">
        <identification>
            <userAgent match="Android 4\.2" />
        </identification>
        <capabilities>
            <capability name="version" value="4.2" />
        </capabilities>
    </gateway>

    <gateway id="PlatformAndroid41" parentID="Platform">
        <identification>
            <userAgent match="Android 4\.1" />
        </identification>
        <capabilities>
            <capability name="version" value="4.1" />
        </capabilities>
    </gateway>

    <gateway id="PlatformAndroid40" parentID="Platform">
        <identification>
            <userAgent match="Android 4\.0" />
        </identification>
        <capabilities>
            <capability name="version" value="4.0" />
        </capabilities>
    </gateway>

    <gateway id="PlatformAndroid30" parentID="Platform">
        <identification>
            <userAgent match="Android 3\.0" />
        </identification>
        <capabilities>
            <capability name="version" value="3.0" />
        </capabilities>
    </gateway>

    <gateway id="PlatformAndroid23" parentID="Platform">
        <identification>
            <userAgent match="Android 2\.3" />
        </identification>
        <capabilities>
            <capability name="version" value="2.3.3" />
        </capabilities>
    </gateway>

    <gateway id="PlatformAndroid22" parentID="Platform">
        <identification>
            <userAgent match="Android 2\.2" />
        </identification>
        <capabilities>
            <capability name="version" value="2.2" />
        </capabilities>
    </gateway>

    <gateway id="PlatformWinMacOs" parentID="Platform">
        <identification>
            <userAgent match="Macintosh" />
        </identification>
        <capabilities>
            <capability name="platform" value="Mac OS" />
        </capabilities>
    </gateway>

    <gateway id="PlatformWinXP" parentID="PlatformWinnt">
        <identification>
            <userAgent match="Windows NT 5\.1" />
        </identification>
        <capabilities>
            <capability name="platform" value="Windows XP" />
        </capabilities>
    </gateway>

    <gateway id="PlatformWin2003" parentID="PlatformWinnt">
        <identification>
            <userAgent match="Windows NT 5\.2" />
        </identification>
        <capabilities>
            <capability name="platform" value="Windows 2003" />
        </capabilities>
    </gateway>

    <gateway id="PlatformWinVista" parentID="PlatformWinnt">
        <identification>
            <userAgent match="Windows NT 6\.0" />
        </identification>
        <capabilities>
            <capability name="platform" value="Vista" />
        </capabilities>
    </gateway>

    <gateway id="PlatformWin7" parentID="PlatformWinnt">
        <identification>
            <userAgent match="Windows NT 6\.1" />
        </identification>
        <capabilities>
            <capability name="platform" value="Windows 7" />
        </capabilities>
    </gateway>

    <gateway id="PlatformWin8" parentID="PlatformWinnt">
        <identification>
            <userAgent match="Windows NT 6\.2" />
        </identification>
        <capabilities>
            <capability name="platform" value="Windows 8" />
        </capabilities>
    </gateway>

    <gateway id="PlatformWin81" parentID="PlatformWinnt">
        <identification>
            <userAgent match="Windows NT 6\.3" />
        </identification>
        <capabilities>
            <capability name="platform" value="Windows 8.1" />
        </capabilities>
    </gateway>
</browsers>
```

(I have posted this as a community wiki so the information can be improved)

Comment: Am I wrong, or will this not tell him if the app is installed, merely if it is possible to do so?

Comment: @MrN00b sorry I don't follow he says he wants to check from a website he is developing in c#.  The ASP.NET way to do this it through the methods I mentioned but the browser info is not up-to date with Microsoft's default one.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - the question is can I check for the existence of an app from a website, and the answer is "probably not". A server side check on the browser won't give him that information.

Comment: @LeeWillis I miss interpreted the question.  You are quite right it's not possible! :)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "no, you can't check what a user has installed on their tablet."

However, you can user agent sniffing to serve different links and if your app registers a Custom URL scheme, then you can have a link that would open an app directly. On your website, the link might point to: `YourApp://something`. You can at least then have the option for people to launch the app from the website (although it's impossible to tell if they have the app installed or not).

That's the best you can do and this is by design. It would be pretty messed up if websites were allowed to see what was on our devices.

EDIT: This is supported on iOS, Android and Windows Phone 8.

EDIT2: Additionally, a link to `YourApp://something` will (at least on Windows Phone, which is all I have handy, but I suspect on iOS and Android as well) prompt the user to install the app instead if they don't have it already.

Comment: Thank you. The website has to know if a specific (and know by the website) app is present on the tablet.